# Foreign Key Mapping

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I'm learing how to access databases with `Linq-To-SQL`

I've just created a database-file with two Tables

```
[Country]
(
   Id INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
   CountryName VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
)

[Address]
(
   Id INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
   Street VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
   HouseNr VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
   ZipCode INT NOT NULL,
   City VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
   CountryId INT NOT NULL,
   CONSTRAINT [FK_Address_Country] FOREIGN KEY ([CountryId]) REFERENCES Country(Id)
)
```

Now I want to create a class called `Address`. At the moment it looks like:

```
[Table(Name = "Address")]    
public class Address
{
   [Column(IsPrimaryKey = true, IsDbGenerated = true)]
   public int Id { get; set; }

   [Column]
   public string Street { get; set; }

   [Column]
   public string HouseNr { get; set; }

   [Column]
   public int ZipCode { get; set; }

   [Column]
   public string City { get; set; }
}
```

My question now is: How do I map the Country as a String-Property? I've read about Association, but I don't really know how to achieve this.

Comment: I would recommend using EF Reverse Engineer CodeFrst which comes with EF Power Tools. But it will give you fluent API. WHich in my opinion is better for coupling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use Linq Mapping Attribute as follows

```
    private string _country;
    [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ColumnAttribute(Storage="_Country", CanBeNull=false)]
    public string Country
    {
        get
        {
            return this._country;
        }
        set
        {
            if ((this._country != value))
            {
                this._country = value;
            }
        }
    }
```